# List department id, department name and the number of managers per department

Tags: mysql, workbench

I'm triyng to list all department id and name, + number of managers per department without duplication.
Could you check these right or wrong and tell me where should I fix? Thank you for reading.

Below is the image of my work ,

[image]

Here are queries I used (inside image but just in case)

```
select  departments.dept_no as department_ID,
    departments.dept_name as department_Name,
    dept_manager.emp_no, count(distinct dept_manager.emp_no) as Numbers_of_Managers
from departments
inner join dept_manager on dept_manager.dept_no=departments.dept_no
group by dept_manager.dept_no;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have `dept_manager.emp_no` in the `SELECT` list. The assignment doesn't ask for it, and you're just selecting one random manager out of the group.

Other than that, it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Barmars answer, you could modify your query as follows to be easier to read:

```
SELECT
    d.dept_no as department_ID,
    d.dept_name as department_Name,
    count(distinct dm.emp_no) as Numbers_of_Managers
FROM
    departments d,
    dept_manager dm
WHERE
    dm.dept_no = d.dept_no
GROUP BY
    dm.dept_no;
```